# Console calculator algorithm that accepts a negative number

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, calculator

I am really stuck with my algorithm trying to improve my code for calculating negative numbers. I would be glad to any advice.

Below is my class with the algorithm I wrote and it doesn't work with negative numbers.

While typing, for example `-90 - 5 =` I get an error on line 46

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:" Index was out of range. Must be
> non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
> Arg_ParamName_Name "

I am limited in the use of third-party components, in the statement of my problem it is written that the calculator must do it itself.

```
public static class Parser
{
    private static readonly char[] ValidOperators = "/*+-".ToCharArray();
    private static readonly int[] OperatorPriorities = new[] {0, 0, 1, 1};
    private static readonly char[] ValidDigits = "0123456789".ToCharArray();

    public static ResultExpressionValue GetUserExpression(string inputData)
    {
        var userExpression = inputData.Replace(" ", "");
        var expressionOperators = userExpression
            .Split(ValidDigits, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(s => s[0])
            .ToList();
        var numbersOfExpression = userExpression
            .Split(ValidOperators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(double.Parse)
            .ToList();
        var operators = new List<char>();
        foreach (int priority in OperatorPriorities.Distinct())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < OperatorPriorities.Length; i++)
            {
                if (OperatorPriorities[i] == priority)
                {
                    operators.Add(ValidOperators[i]);
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < expressionOperators.Count; i++)
            {
                if (operators.Contains(expressionOperators[i]))
                {
                    numbersOfExpression[i] = AddsTheResultOfTheParsedNumbers(numbersOfExpression[i],
                        numbersOfExpression[i + 1], expressionOperators[i]);
                    numbersOfExpression.RemoveAt(i + 1);
                    expressionOperators.RemoveAt(i);
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }
        if (Double.IsPositiveInfinity(numbersOfExpression[0]))
        {
            throw new DivideByZeroException(
                $"{Environment.NewLine}Division by zero is not possible{Environment.NewLine}");
        }
        return new ResultExpressionValue(numbersOfExpression);
    }

    private static double AddsTheResultOfTheParsedNumbers(double left, double right, char op) => op switch
    {
        '*' => left * right,
        '/' => left / right,
        '+' => left + right,
        '-' => left - right,
        _ => throw new NotSupportedException()
    };
}
```

Comment: I strongly suspect the reason why you cannot enter negative numbers is because `'-'` doesn't feature in your valid digits  `private static readonly char[] validDigits = "0123456789".ToCharArray();`

Comment: corrected sir description

Comment: @CaiusJard. Z Tried your solution, didn't help.
For example: -1 + 10 = 11

Comment: That's not a solution, it's a comment. Please familiarize yourself with the difference, otherwise SO will be quite a confusing place!

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/amp/

Comment: Your approach is wrong. You should use grammar for this kind of parsing problems. Read more about LR/LL parsers - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser. Basically, you have stack, you add characters of input in it, and when there is recognizable structure on TOP of the stack (number, decimal, double, a*b, a-b, etc, you can make dictionary of those) - you transform this structure into another one and replace it on stack (pop multiple/push one). Repeat until there is one element in stack, which is your final expression/result.

Comment: I will definitely try

Comment: "Programming a console based calculator" is pretty much a programming 101 grade assignment, yet your code is chock full of fairly advanced stuff that you seem not to understand - LINQ, Regex, pattern matching - are you perhaps reaping the benefits of having got other people on SO to complete previous parts of your homework for you?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach should be using syntax analysis. In particular LR parser will be enough - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser. Compilers use this. There is even gallery of various grammars which describes not only math expressions, but C# itself in ANTLR framework gallery :  https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/csharp

Or for math: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/arithmetic/arithmetic.g4

But you need to do it by hand, so here is some pseudo-algo for you.

Suppose you have some kind of expression:  `-90*1.023-3+3`
It consists of terminals. Terminal - is a small element, which can be extracted with any FSA. Regex is FSA on character stream, so use it to first extract things you  recognize (you can of course don't make this step, but Your grammar in this case will be enormous, describing how to parse expression AND numbers):

```
T(-),T(90),T(*),T(1.023),T(-),T(3),T(+),T(3)
```

Next, you need to use Grammar with multiple Rules where Left side contains non-terminal and Right side contains terminals+non-terminals pattern:

```
Expression = Expression * Expression 
Expression = Expression + Expression 
Expression = (Expression)
Expression = -Expression 
Expression = Number
```

Next, you build a stack pushing your terminals one-by-one, and when you see **Right** side of any rule matched **on TOP** of your stack - you **replace it with Left** side of your matched Rule. Repeat it until you can't, then push another terminal into stack. Repeat. Operation priority can be done by rearranging order.

In the end you should get one non-terminal, which is basically a tree representation of your expression, otherwise - throw parsing error. Tree will be in Reverse Polish notation (https://www.dcode.fr/reverse-polish-notation) which is easy to traverse and calculate from bottom up.

LR parser is pretty powerful and simple concept and used among many generations of developers.